# Pygame Highscores won't sort

Tags: python, sorting, pygame

Hello someone please help me, this is a function which sorts the players by their high score. It's not sorting though.

```
def sortByScore(inputPlayerScore):
    return inputPlayerScore[1]


def highscore():


    try:
       scores = open("scores.txt", "r")
       highScores = list()   # place all your processed lines in here
       for line in scores.readlines():
           lineParts = line.split(": ")
           if len(lineParts) > 1:
               lineParts[-1] = lineParts[-1].replace("\n", "")
               highScores.append(lineParts)   # sorting uses lists
       print(sorted(highScores, key=sortByScore, reverse = True))   # get this out of for loop
    except Exception:
        pass
```

The input file is:

```
jkh: 32
daasd: 6
dasdf: 9
wfsdwf: 125
dada: 5
jkh: 62
```

Comment: Please add the `sortByScore` function and a few lines of the "scores.txt" file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it's sorting the scores *as strings* (and so, for example, "123" comes before "32").

**Hint:** you need to convert them to integers either before sorting or in your key function.